# Why does getpeername() return OK yet the result is not as expected?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp

The problem has been resolved. The root cause is that I passed a C++ temporary object as sockaddr* of getpeername(), which was automatically destroyed after getpeername() returned.

Therefore, the net result was full of 0s.

Sorry for my carelessness. I've voted to close this post. Please vote to close, too.

---

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void server()
{
    sockaddr_in server_addr {};
    server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server_addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);

    SOCKET s_listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bind(s_listening, (sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    listen(s_listening, 5);

    while (true) 
    {
        auto s_new = accept(s_listening, 0, 0);

        sockaddr_in client_addr {};
        int size = sizeof(client_addr);
        auto ret = getpeername(s_new, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &size); 
        //
        // ret is 0, which means the call to getpeername is OK. 
        // But client_addr is full of 0s rather than "127.0.0.1:4". Why?
        //
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread(server).detach();
    SOCKET s_client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sockaddr_in client_addr {};
    client_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    client_addr.sin_port        = htons(4);

    bind(s_client, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));

    sockaddr_in server_addr {};
    server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server_addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);

    connect(s_client, (sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    getchar();
}
```

The code is compiled with VC++ 2012. However, although the call to function getpeername returns OK, the returned data is wrong (full of 0s), why?

Comment: OT: Why don't you just use the 2nd and 3rd parameter of `accept()` to get the peer?

Comment: This is highly simplified code to focus on the key issue. My real purpose is to get peer info by socket only long after accept().

Comment: In `sockaddr_in client_addr {};`, what is the purpose of the empty bracket pair? Does this even compile? There's no `=` so it's not initialization.

Comment: @unwind， In C++11, it's legal.

Comment: Why do you expect a `sockaddr_in` to contain "127.0.0.1:4" when it isn't specified to do so?

Comment: why did you removed your initial question?

Answer (score 3):

`getpeername()` initialises a `sockaddr_<something>` structure. If `<something>` equals `in` it is holding ip-address and port in binary format.

It does *not* carry a character buffer holding any ASCII representation of the peer's name/address and port.

Also values in `sockaddr_in` are held in network bytes order.

To print the address and port as expressed by the comment in the OP's source snippet, you can do as follows:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

...

int sd = -1; /* init to invalid socket */

... /* get sd a proper value */

sockaddr_in sa = {0}; /* init to all zeros */
socklen_t sl = sizeof(sa);
if (getpeername(sd, (sockaddr *) &sa,  &sl))
  perror("getpeername() failed");
else
  printf("peer is: %s:%hu\n", inetntoa(sa.sinaddr), ntohs(sa.sin_port));
```